# Swift inputing characters and strings into a dictionary

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, function, dictionary

How would I go about Writing a function that takes in an array of strings and outputs a dictionary with the first character of each string as a key and the remaining as objects?

Comment: What you have tried? show your code and what problem you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

Writing this piece of code for you without seeing any trials from your side, just because you are new on StackOverflow. And I'm seeing the message from StackOverflow that *"Corey Townsend is a new contributor. **Be nice**..."*
So I'm just being nice for you as a welcome and here is your code.

```
let arr = ["car", "cat", "dog", "ball", "flower", "notebook", "fire"]

func createDictionaryFromArrayAsCoreyWants(arr:[String]) -> [String:String] {

    var dict:[String:String] = [:]
    arr.forEach({ (word:String) in

        let strKey = String(word.prefix(1))
        let startIndex: String.Index = word.index(word.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
        let strValue = String(word[startIndex..<word.endIndex])
        dict[strKey] = strValue
        print(strKey + " : " + strValue)
    })

    return dict
}

let d = createDictionaryFromArrayAsCoreyWants(arr: arr)
print(d)
```

**Addition**

Just saw a comment on another answer by 'Alex Bailer' so adding one more function for you. Enjoy...

```
func createDictionaryFromArrayAsCoreyWants(arr:[String]) -> [String:[String]] {

    var dict:[String:[String]] = [:]
    arr.forEach({ (word:String) in

        let strKey = String(word.prefix(1))
        let startIndex: String.Index = word.index(word.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
        let strValue = String(word[startIndex..<word.endIndex])
        if let a = dict[strKey] {
            dict[strKey] = a + [strValue]
        } else {
            dict[strKey] = [strValue]
        }
        print(strKey + " : " + strValue)
    })

    return dict
}

let d = createDictionaryFromArrayAsCoreyWants(arr: arr)
print(d)
```

**Output:**

```
["d": ["og"], "n": ["otebook"], "b": ["all"], "c": ["ar", "at"], "f": ["lower", "ire"]]
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this what are you looking for?

```
let d = Dictionary(grouping: array, by: {$0.prefix(1)})
```

with array:

```
let array = ["car", "cat", "dog", "ball", "flower", "notebok", "fire"]
```

It prints:

```
["b": ["ball"], "f": ["flower", "fire"], "d": ["dog"], "c": ["car", "cat"], "n": ["notebok"]]
```

And then, remove the first letter from values:

```
for key in d.keys {
    let values = d[key]

    let start = String.Index(encodedOffset: 1)
    d[key] = values?.compactMap({ String($0[start...]) })
}
```

Output:

```
["f": ["lower", "ire"], "d": ["og"], "b": ["all"], "c": ["ar", "at"], "n": ["otebok"]]
```

Comment: The output should be ["b": ["all"], "f": ["lower", "ire"], "d": ["og"], "c": ["ar", "at"], "n": ["otebok"]]